# Hibernate Search [5.11.5.Final] dynamic numeric properties: Cannot automatically determine the field type for field '...'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm having some trouble properly indexing dynamic numeric fields, it seems they are always indexed as strings.

In my understanding, when indexing dynamic numeric fields I must use dynamic templates:

```
PUT /com.product.product

{
    "mappings": {
        "com.product.Product": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "numeric_sort": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "*",
                        "match_pattern": "regex",
                        "match": "^sort_num_.*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "double"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

That i'm uploading in an event listener:

```
@Configuration
@Transactional
public abstract class DynamicTemplateConfig {
    @EventListener
    public void addDynamicTemplates(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        if (this.searchIndexingIsActive) {
            this.addDynamicTemplates();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And i'm indexing the properties in a field bridge:

```
public class PropertyValueFieldBridge implements FieldBridge {
    ...
    private void indexBigDecimalProperties(Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions, PropertyBigDecimal property) {
            String fieldName = PREFIX_SORT + NUMERIC + DELIMITER + property.getProperty().getCode();
            Double indexedValue = property.getValue().doubleValue();
    
            luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(
                    fieldName,
                    indexedValue,
                    document);
        }

    }
```

After indexing these BigDecimal properties I always end with a string property indexed:

```
"_source": {
    "id": "1",
    "sort_id": 1,
    "filter_id": 1,
    "sort_num_quantity": "115.0"
}
```

And when i try to sort through this property i have the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Cannot automatically determine the field type for field 'sort_num_quantity'. Use byField(String, Sort.Type) to provide the sort type explicitly.
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.sort.impl.SortFieldStates.getCurrentSortFieldTypeFromMetamodel(SortFieldStates.java:177) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.5.Final.jar:5.11.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.sort.impl.SortFieldStates.determineCurrentSortFieldTypeAutomaticaly(SortFieldStates.java:150) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.5.Final.jar:5.11.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.sort.impl.ConnectedSortContext.byField(ConnectedSortContext.java:42) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.5.Final.jar:5.11.5.Final]
```

I'm trying to avoid using the `byField(String, Sort.Type)` since it requires the explicity verification of every property, which i might not know the name and type.

Am i doing something wrong in the indexing process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. The experimental Elasticsearch integration in Hibernate Search 5 does not really support dynamic fields. You can't specify the type of fields in advance, and it apparently defaults to the String type for dynamic fields.

Upgrading to Hibernate Search 6 (currently in the Candidate Release phase) would be a solution, since [it supports dynamic fields through field templates](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-index-field-dsl-dynamic)
The Hibernate Search 6 API is different, however, so migrating may require significant work.